# Download a whole website with wget (or other) including all its downloadable content

Tags: downloads, wget

I'm trying to download winamp's website in case they shut it down. I need to download literally everything.

I tried once with `wget` and I managed to download the website itself, but when I try to download any file from it it gives a file without an extension or name. How can I fix that?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/970323/using-wget-to-copy-website-with-proper-layout-for-offline-browsing

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You may need to mirror the website completely, but be aware that some links may really dead. You can use HTTrack or wget:

```
wget -r http://winapp.com # or whatever
```

With HTTrack, first install it:

```
sudo apt-get install httrack
```

now run it just 1 external link:

```
httrack --ext-depth=1 http://winapp.com
```

This will download the winapp CDN files, but not the files in the files in the files in the whole internet.

Answer (score 34):

This is the most effective and easy way I've found to create a complete mirror of a website that can be viewed locally with working scripts, styles, etc:

```
wget -mpEk "url"
```

Using `-m` (mirror) instead of `-r` is preferred as it intuitively downloads assets and you don't have to specify recursion depth, using mirror generally determines the correct depth to return a functioning site.

The commands `-p -E -k` ensure that you're not downloading entire pages that might be linked to (e.g. Link to a Twitter profile results in you downloading Twitter code) while including all pre-requisite files (JavaScript, css, etc.) that the site needs. Proper site structure is preserved as well (instead of one big .html file with embedded scripts/stylesheet that can sometimes be the output.

It's fast, I have never had to limit anything to get it to work and the resulting directory looks better than simply using the `-r "url"` arg and provides better insight into how the site was put together, especially if you're reverse-engineering for educational purposes.

If you end up getting kicked from the site's IP, or the download stops, try running the same command, but with: `--wait="duration"` enabled. This adds a duration between requests so as not to trigger any DDoS flags on their end.

Note that if you're downloading a web-app or a site with lots of JavaScript that was compiled from TypeScript, you won't be able to get the TypeScript that was used initially, only what is compiled and sent to the browser. Take this into consideration if the site is very script heavy.

Answer (score 14):

```
wget -p -k http://somewebsite.com
```

From `man wget`

```
-p
--page-requisites
   This option causes Wget to download all the files that are
   necessary to properly display a given HTML page.  This includes
   such things as inlined images, sounds, and referenced stylesheets.

   Ordinarily, when downloading a single HTML page, any requisite
   documents that may be needed to display it properly are not
   downloaded.  Using -r together with -l can help, but since Wget
   does not ordinarily distinguish between external and inlined
   documents, one is generally left with "leaf documents" that are
   missing their requisites.

   For instance, say document 1.html contains an "<IMG>" tag
   referencing 1.gif and an "<A>" tag pointing to external document
   2.html.  Say that 2.html is similar but that its image is 2.gif and
   it links to 3.html.  Say this continues up to some arbitrarily high
   number.

   If one executes the command:

           wget -r -l 2 http://<site>/1.html

   then 1.html, 1.gif, 2.html, 2.gif, and 3.html will be downloaded.
   As you can see, 3.html is without its requisite 3.gif because Wget
   is simply counting the number of hops (up to 2) away from 1.html in
   order to determine where to stop the recursion.  However, with this
   command:

           wget -r -l 2 -p http://<site>/1.html

   all the above files and 3.html's requisite 3.gif will be
   downloaded.  Similarly,

           wget -r -l 1 -p http://<site>/1.html

   will cause 1.html, 1.gif, 2.html, and 2.gif to be downloaded.  One
   might think that:

           wget -r -l 0 -p http://<site>/1.html

   would download just 1.html and 1.gif, but unfortunately this is not
   the case, because -l 0 is equivalent to -l inf---that is, infinite
   recursion.  To download a single HTML page (or a handful of them,
   all specified on the command-line or in a -i URL input file) and
   its (or their) requisites, simply leave off -r and -l:

           wget -p http://<site>/1.html

   Note that Wget will behave as if -r had been specified, but only
   that single page and its requisites will be downloaded.Links from
   that page to external documents will not be followed.  Actually, to
   download a single page and all its requisites (even if they exist
   on separate websites), and make sure the lot displays properly
   locally, this author likes to use a few options in addition to -p:

          wget -E -H -k -K -p http://<site>/<document>

   To finish off this topic, it's worth knowing that Wget's idea of an
   external document link is any URL specified in an "<A>" tag, an
   "<AREA>" tag, or a "<LINK>" tag other than "<LINK
   REL="stylesheet">".

  ==================================================================

 -k
 --convert-links
   After the download is complete, convert the links in the document to make them suitable for local viewing.  This affects not only the visible hyperlinks, but any part of the document that
   links to external content, such as embedded images, links to style sheets, hyperlinks to non-HTML content, etc.

   Each link will be changed in one of the two ways:

   ·   The links to files that have been downloaded by Wget will be changed to refer to the file they point to as a relative link.

       Example: if the downloaded file /foo/doc.html links to /bar/img.gif, also downloaded, then the link in doc.html will be modified to point to ../bar/img.gif.  This kind of transformation
       works reliably for arbitrary combinations of directories.

   ·   The links to files that have not been downloaded by Wget will be changed to include host name and absolute path of the location they point to.

       Example: if the downloaded file /foo/doc.html links to /bar/img.gif (or to ../bar/img.gif), then the link in doc.html will be modified to point to http://hostname/bar/img.gif.

   Because of this, local browsing works reliably: if a linked file was downloaded, the link will refer to its local name; if it was not downloaded, the link will refer to its full Internet
   address rather than presenting a broken link.  The fact that the former links are converted to relative links ensures that you can move the downloaded hierarchy to another directory.

   Note that only at the end of the download can Wget know which links have been downloaded.  Because of that, the work done by -k will be performed at the end of all the downloads.

  --convert-file-only
   This option converts only the filename part of the URLs, leaving the rest of the URLs untouched. This filename part is sometimes referred to as the "basename", although we avoid that term
   here in order not to cause confusion.

   It works particularly well in conjunction with --adjust-extension, although this coupling is not enforced. It proves useful to populate Internet caches with files downloaded from different
   hosts.

   Example: if some link points to //foo.com/bar.cgi?xyz with --adjust-extension asserted and its local destination is intended to be ./foo.com/bar.cgi?xyz.css, then the link would be converted
   to //foo.com/bar.cgi?xyz.css. Note that only the filename part has been modified. The rest of the URL has been left untouched, including the net path ("//") which would otherwise be
   processed by Wget and converted to the effective scheme (ie. "http://").
```

sorry for my bad indentation :(

Answer (score 3):

Try: `wget -r --no-parent http://www.mysite.com/dict`

r means recursively

Answer (score 0):

If You want to download everything associated with the link you have
You can try this

```
wget -r -U "BrowserName" "Url"
```

You may wanna use `--wait="duration"` to avoid your ip being blocked.
Its weird requesting page after page without wait periods. that's not human

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  It would be a vast improvement to this answer to improve your grammar, or at least to approve the suggested edit...

Comment: `wget -m` could also be used instead of `-r`

Comment: Use `--random-wait` with `--wait=X` in order to avoid blocks further.

Comment: @Patrick Would you care to post a full answer? Your comment sounds interesting.